# C++ Sandbox Game Low Performance Difficulty

Tags: c++, performance

I started Learning C++ yesterday And In that time i was rewriting my java "Falling Sand" Sandbox Game code in C++ using SFML (bit simplified since i don't  know C++). but Performance in C++ was  much worse in than java, what could be the reason for it, I Know this is very  unfocused question, but  my code is simple, i probably have a newbie  mistakes which should be easy to correct.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    sf::Clock sclock;
    const int WIDTH = 1440, HEIGHT = 960;
    const char Blank = 0, Sand = 1, Water = 2;
    const char* title = "Sandbox Simulation";
    char map[WIDTH*HEIGHT];
    sf::Vector2i mousePos;
    int dist(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
        return sqrt(pow(x1 - x2, 2) + pow(y1 - y2, 2));
    }
    int localBrushSize = 48;
    short halfBrush = (short)floor(localBrushSize / 2);
    char chosen = Sand;
    void place() {
        int randY = 0;
        int randX = 0;
        randX = randY = 1;
        for (int y = mousePos.y - halfBrush; y <= mousePos.y + halfBrush; y += randY) {
            for (int x = mousePos.x - halfBrush; x <= mousePos.x + halfBrush; x += randX) {
                int I = x + y * WIDTH;
                int distance = dist(mousePos.x, x, mousePos.y, y);
                if (distance < halfBrush && I > 0) {
    
                        map[I] = chosen;
    
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
    float Delta_Time() {
        return sclock.restart().asSeconds();
    }
    int main() {
        map[11111] = 2;
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), title);
        sf::Event evnt;
        sf::RectangleShape pixel(sf::Vector2f(1.0f, 1.0f));
        window.clear();
        while (window.isOpen()) {
            while (window.pollEvent(evnt)) {
                switch (evnt.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)) {
                mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
                place();
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
                    int I = x + y * WIDTH;
                    switch (map[I]) {
                    case Sand:
                        pixel.setPosition(x, y);
                        pixel.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
                        window.draw(pixel);
                        break;
                    case Water:
                        pixel.setPosition(x, y);
                        pixel.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
                        window.draw(pixel);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
    
                
                window.display();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: No, ran it on debug mode, but now i tried in release mode, but still, same performance, also this  is not the first time  i got issues in c++, i was rewriting  tilemap game and performance was much worse in C++, so clearly am doing something wrong, C++ is almost always faster

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to eliminate the most obvious cause of slow performance. Good luck.

Comment: Drawing pixel by pixel is very slow. This may be even slower in SFML because you are crossing the border between CPU and GPU for every pixel. Java might fill a framebuffer and flushes it all at once.

Comment: Thanks, thats  probably whats up, i will optimize

Comment: could not do it

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make a cached / "framebuffer" like this

TOTALLY untested concept code. WIDTH/HEIGHT might be mixed up, endianess is not OK, etc.

```cpp
    sf::Image image; 
    sf:Image.create(WIDTH, HEIGHT, sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
    sf::Sprite       sprite;
    std::array<sf::Uint8, WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4> pixels; // you can reuse this. The 4 is the size of RGBA
    
    ...
    
        for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
                int offset = (x + y * WIDTH) * 4;
                pixels[offset] = sf::Color::Yellow.toInteger(); // in case BIG/Litte endian confusion you might have to do the below.
                //pixels[offset + 0 ] = 255; // R?
                //pixels[offset + 1 ] = 255; // G?
                //pixels[offset + 2 ] = 255; // B?
                //pixels[offset + 3 ] = 255; // A?
            }
        }

        image.LoadFromPixels(WIDTH, HEIGHT, pixels);
        sprite.SetImage(image);
        window.Draw(sprite);
        window.Display();
```

Comment: is not it better to put HEIGHT loop above the WIDTH loop?

Comment: SFML::Image stuff does not work  with me do i  need to download anything

Comment: @PGGAMINGXD try it out, in any case I think your right.

Comment: @PGGAMINGXD it should be in the newest https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Image.php

Comment: its not  sf::Image        image(WIDTH, HEIGHT, sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
its 
sf::Image        image;
sf:Image.create(WIDTH, HEIGHT, sf::Color(0, 0, 0));

Comment: @PGGAMINGXD The double loop is likely also not needed as both arrays are one dimensional and of same dimension and can be replaced with a single loop.

Comment: but is it faster  tho